# AWS DocDB $project Requires Outputs, doesnt match mongo API

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I am using the $project stage in an aggregation pipeline using Pymongo on AWS DocumentDB, like so:

```
{ '$project': { 'foo': 0 } }
```

This results in the following error:

> $projection requires at least one output field

As far as I can tell, the mongo docs state that as of Mongo version 3.4 you can use $project to specify *exclusions* of fields (see: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). The example they provide looks like:

```
db.books.aggregate( [ { $project : { "lastModified": 0 } } ] )
```

Does docdb not match this part of the API spec? or am I missing something?

EDIT: I'm also unable to use the _id filter specifically, which is also highlighted in mongo docs.

```
{'$project': {'_id': 0}}
```

Comment: This syntax is fine, however DocumentDB has its own implementation that can sometimes vary from the original mongoDB functionality. It appears that when it comes to the `$project` stage they do not allow this type of usage. however there is no explicit mention of this in their docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding just _id is not currently supported, i.e. `{ '$project': { '_id': 0 } }`

But, projecting a non existing field can enforce exclusion: `{ '$project': { '_id': 0, 'foo_field': 0 } }`

Comment: Yep, this worked! Thanks. It looks like I was wrong and if you do `{ '$projection': {'foo': 0}}` it DOES work, it only fails on `_id` specifically. But excluding some other field thats not present does in fact seem to work fine